# What is the correct .NET_Folder to store required DLLs references?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

VisualStudio 2008 has a few options when it comes to ASP_Folders (ASP_GlobalResources, ASP_LocalResources, ASP_DATA, etc).  I have a few dependency DLLs like (DotNetOpenAuth) that I will like to store in SVN so that when people checkout the solution they don't have to install anything in their development machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct folder is the [Bin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295391.aspx) folder. Anyways it's not recommended to add this to your SVN repository. A common approach is to add an extra folder which you could call lib, where you store the dll's that are required for a successful build of your application.

Answer (score 1):

The correct ASP.NET folder for DLL's would be the Bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

I generally store references in a lib folder that is a sibling to the source folder. The parent to both those folders is the root for that project. Something like this:

```
lib/
    reference.dll
build/
    buildscript.xml
source/
    SolutionFile.sln
    ProjectA/
        ProjectA.csproj
    ProjectB/
        ProjectB.csproj
```

Visual Studio will store the references as relative paths (....\lib\reference.dll) so version control should not be an issue.